# Nodejs: Comparing results of two async requests

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request, web-crawler

I looked at other questions regarding this topic but can't wrap my head around how to implement it in this case.

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Visit site and get content (body)
2. Visit matching test site and get content (body)
3. Compare content
4. Crawl links on page1
5. Crawl links on page2
6. Continue

The problem I am having at the moment is that I cannot compare the content because the requests are not waiting for each other. 
Here's what my code looks like at the moment.

```
require('colors');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var jsdiff = require('diff');
var URL = require('url-parse');

var PROD_START_URL = "https://www.somesite.org";
var MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT = 100;

var pagesVisited = {};
var numPagesVisited = 0;
var pagesToVisit = [];

var globalProdContent;
var globalTestContent;

var url = new URL(PROD_START_URL);
var baseUrl = url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname;

pagesToVisit.push(PROD_START_URL);
crawl();

function crawl() {
  if(numPagesVisited >= MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT) {
    console.log("Reached max limit of number of pages to visit.");
    return;
  }
  var nextPage = pagesToVisit.pop();
  if (nextPage in pagesVisited) {
    // We've already visited this page, so repeat the crawl
    crawl();
  } else {
    // New page we haven't visited
    visitPage(nextPage, crawl);
  }
}

function visitPage(url, callback) {
  // Add page to our set
  pagesVisited[url] = true;
  numPagesVisited++;

  // Make the request
  console.log("Visiting page " + url);
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
     // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)
     console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
     if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
       callback();
       return;
     }
     // Parse the document body
     var $ = cheerio.load(body);
     globalProdContent = $("#wrapper").text();

     // Build new URL for test site
     var testURL = url.replace("https://www.somesite.org", "http://matching.testsite");

     // Scrape test site
     scrapeTestContent(testURL);


     collectInternalLinks($);
     callback();
  });
}

function collectInternalLinks($) {
    var relativeLinks = [];
    relativeLinks = $("a[href]");

    console.log("Found " + relativeLinks.length + " relative links on page");
    relativeLinks.each(function() {
        pagesToVisit.push(baseUrl + "/" + $(this).attr('href'));
    });
}

function scrapeTestContent(testURL) {
    console.log("Visiting matching testpage " + testURL);
    request(testURL, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
        if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
            callback();
        return;
        }

        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        globalTestContent = $("#wrapper").text();
        console.log(globalTestContent);

    });
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this or am I completely off the track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in two ways:
 1. Add callback to `scrapeTestContent`

```
    function scrapeTestContent(testURL, cb) {
        ...
        request(testURL, function(error, response, body) {
            cb();
        });

    In visitPage,

    function visitPage(url, callback) {
        ...
        scrapeTestContent(testURL, () => collectInternalLinks($));
    }
```

2. Using ES6 promises. In `scrapeTestContent()` return `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {}`. Then in `visitPage`, use following construct: `scrapeTestContent(testUrl).then(() => collectInternalLinks($))`